# put NSData and a file extension to pasteboard

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsdata, nspasteboard

I've been searching online for a long time the answer to a question that has left me locked.

I have a subclassed NSView and want it to be draggable. When released into the desktop want to be saved as a file with the NSData that I have assigned (and also an extension that has been assigned).

I think I need to make the right call to:

```
[self dragImage:pic at:NSMakePoint(50, 50) offset:NSMakeSize(50, 50) event:theEvent pasteboard:pboard source:self slideBack:NO];
```

but I've been looking for hours and have not found anything to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using one of the file dragging methods on `NSView`?

```
- (BOOL)dragFile:(NSString *)filename fromRect:(NSRect)rect slideBack:(BOOL)aFlag event:(NSEvent *)event;
- (BOOL)dragPromisedFilesOfTypes:(NSArray *)typeArray fromRect:(NSRect)rect source:(id)sourceObject slideBack:(BOOL)aFlag event:(NSEvent *)event;
```

Comment: I think that I need is: "Dragging File Promises"

Comment: -(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent { [self dragPromisedFilesOfTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"pdf"] fromRect:[self frame] source:self slideBack:YES event:theEvent]; [super mouseDragged:theEvent]; }

Comment: - (NSArray *)namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:(NSURL *)destination { NSLog(@"destination = %@", destination); NSRect r = [self bounds] ; NSData *data = [self dataWithPDFInsideRect:r] ; NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0] ; [temp appendString:[destination path]] ; [temp appendString:@"/test.pdf"] ; // filename [data writeToFile:temp atomically:YES] ; return [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"test"] ; }